# how to make this javascript application accessible?

Tags: javascript, accessibility, web-applications

Im making an FTP client, which will rely a lot on javascript.

When browsing through the files, you can navigate using the arrow keys. I add a class of .selected to the currently selected filename, but how can I make this clear to screenreaders? How do I make them focus on the current filename?

Would the best way be to make every filename an anchor, which will get the focus when the filename is selected? And also, where can I find a good guide on web application accessibility? I know the W3C has a checklist for content accessibility, but most of the points there don't apply to web apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to do this is perhaps to have a series of checkboxes, each with a unique ID, paired with a label:

```
<input id="chk01" type="checkbox"/><label for="chk01">File1.txt</label>
```

Using this technique, the input is doing the work of exposing a selected-ness for you, while the label takes care of associating it with the name: when focus goes to the checkbox, the screenreader will automatically read out the associated label text. It's all plain HTML, nothing special required. You're free of course to add in selection coloring on top of this - so long as you keep it in sync with checkbox state.

It may be possible to do something similar with A tags; you can use [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria.php) properties to set role="listitem" and aria-selected="true"/"false" as appropriate on the items, with role="list" on the parent container. A screenreader will then read these out as list items, rather than links. This technique is more involved, however, and would really need to be tested with an actual screen reader (eg JAWS, or the freely-available NVDA) to ensure it works.

Comment: thx man. Do you know if it's semantically correct to put a table row inside a label? This way, the checkbox, which will go insie the first table row cell is automatically associated with the filename.

Comment: TR has to be within a TABLE (or TBODY, etc). But you can separate the input and the label, so the checkbox can be in one column, the label in the other. The association between the two is all done with the for="id-of-checkbox" attribute on the label.

Comment: No, it's not semantically correct to put a label around a whole table row. LABEL is inline, TR is a table-row element. Besides, the row has multiple things in it (file name, file size, permissions) while the LABEL element assumes a 1-to-1 relationship between the label and the corresponding input. If you need this, look into the ARIA properties aria-label and aria-labelledby.  http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-wai-aria-20100916/states_and_properties#aria-labelledby

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a javascript framework to help with accessibility in conjunction with [WAI-ARIA](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/WAI-ARIA) For examples of accessible jQuery see
https://github.com/fnagel/jQuery-Accessible-RIA/wiki and for examples of accessible drag and drop with WAI-ARIA see
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/accessible-drag-and-drop/

Comment: For self-education purposes, I will not be using a UI framework in this project.

Answer (score 1):

First - make sure your basics are covered. The Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) don't cover interactivity well, but many of its points remain applicable to web applications.

Next - learn about the ARIA standard for Accessible Rich Internet Applications.  This will cover a lot of the interactivity you're trying for.

Some relevant links:

- http://webaim.org/ for common accessibility problems, plus some invaluable surveys of screen reader usage
- http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/wcag.php - overview of WCAG 2.0
- http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria.php - overview of ARIA

There are a number of books on accessibility, which tend to get outdated fairly fast. Sadly, I'm not aware of any book-length discussions of ARIA -- it's still in development. Try reading the specs.

Last but not least -- get a screen reader and learn to use it.  Formal compliance with accessibility standards is great, but nothing beats real testing.  NVDA is a free and fully featured screen reader that has decent support for ARIA: http://nvda-project.org/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> When browsing through the files, you can navigate using the arrow keys.

Building upon a previous answer that neglected this feature, wrap the entire widget in a div with role=application. This notifies the screen reader that JavaScript will be used and will allow the user to navigate the widget with the arrow keys while using a screen reader. The excerpt below details how to design the widget to be accessible. Yes, it's not the simplest solution, but it is the most complete. Take your pick.

Description: A widget that allows the user to select one or more items from a   list of choices. (`listbox`). Keyboard Interaction:

- <kbd>Tab</kbd>: When a list is tabbed to, select the first item if   nothing else is already selected. A second tab will take the user out of the   widget to the next tab stop on the page.
- Up/down arrows navigate up and down the list.
- <kbd>Shift+Up Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Shift+Down Arrow</kbd> move and extend the selection.
- Typing letter or several letters to navigate (same letter   goes to each item starting with that, different letters go to first item   starting with that entire string).
- <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd>: If the current item has an associated context   menu, then this key combination will launch that menu.
- **Selection**

  - Checkbox - <kbd>Space</kbd> toggles checkboxes, if the list items are checkable
  - Selectable List Items

    - <kbd>Space</kbd> acts as a toggle to select and deselect the current   item. If previous items have been selected, it also deselects them and selects   the current item.
    - <kbd>Shift+Space</kbd> selects contiguous items from the last   selected item to the current item.
    - <kbd>Ctrl+Arrow</kbd> moves without selecting.
    - <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> selects non-contiguous items and adds the   current selected item to all previously selected items.
    - <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> - It is recommended a checkbox, link or other   method be used to select all. The <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> key could be used to provide the   shortcut key.

It is recommended the developer use different styling for   the selection when the list is not focused (hint: non-active selection is often   shown with a lighter background color). WAI-ARIA Roles, States, and Properties:

- The listbox container  has a role of `listbox`.
- Each entry in the listbox should have a role `option` and should be DOM  children of `listbox`.
- If is not a DOM child of listbox, then it should be referenced in the listbox by   `aria-owns`.
- If all items in the listbox are not DOM children of the listbox, then  set their `aria-setsize` and `aria-posinset` accordingly; otherwise, this information cannot  be computed for context by the user agent.
- If the listbox is not part of another widget, then it should have a visible `aria-label` referenced on the listbox by 
  `aria-labelledby`.
- Each selected list item should have `aria-selected`="true".

Examples:

[Single select listbox](http://codetalks.org/source/widgets/listbox/listbox.html)

[Listbox in an iframe](http://codetalks.org/source/widgets/listbox/listbox-owner.html)

Refer to the [authoring practices for accessible widgets](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/) for examples and more information.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, YUI has a large amount of support for ARIA.

See:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=kloots-yuiconf2009-a11y

Make sure your solution conforms to ARIA:

http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria.php

HTH